# How to initialize a library in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to work with this react-native library, and in the documentation it says this:

**Initialize Library
Somewhere high up in your project and way before calling any other method exposed by this library, your index file or equivalent is a good spot, ensure you initialize the library with your public key as follows:**

```
import RNPaystack from 'react-native-paystack';

RNPaystack.init({ publicKey: 'YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY_HERE' });
```

How do I do this, without getting null object is not a function.
In my app.js I tried it with useEffect, tried with componentwillmount , tried several ways, same error.
I feel I'm doing it wrongly.
Can someone tell how to initialize a library properly in react native.

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you linked the module?

Comment: I'm using expo.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use RNPaystack in expo without ejecting.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely happening because you haven't linked the native modules properly. That's expected as you mentioned you're using Expo, which doesn't allow you to add custom native code. If you want to use this library, you'll have to eject from Expo. See [the docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/).